# Error in angular JS,

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to run an AngularJS simple app, but id returns an error

**Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module photoApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/unpr?p0=%24r...

Description
This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.
In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.**

[https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=photoApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.19%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngResource%26p1%3DError%2](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=photoApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.19%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngResource%26p1%3DError%252)

It's my photoApp js file

`var modulo = angular.module('photoApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap']);`

```
modulo.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/photos',
                      { templateUrl: 'PhotoAlbum.aspx', controller: "PhotoListCtrl" });
    $routeProvider.when('/photos/:id',
                      { templateUrl: 'PhotoDetail.aspx', controller: "PhotoDetailCtrl" });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/photos' });
});


modulo.controller('PhotoListCtrl', function ($scope) {
    PhotoListCtrl($scope);
});

modulo.controller('PhotoDetailCtrl', function ($scope) {
    PhotoDetailCtrl($scope);
});

function PhotoListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.photos = [
    {"file": "balloons.jpg", "description": "Palloncini colorati.", 
     "tags": "palloncini giallo rosso verde colori"},
    {"file": "cards.jpg", "description": "Asso di cuori.",
     "tags": "carte da gioco asso di cuori"},
    {"file": "watchmaker.jpg", "description": "L'orologiaio.",
     "tags": "orologio orologiaio occhi"}
  ];
}

function PhotoDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.photo = photos[$routeParams.id - 1];
}
```

It's the main page of the module

```
<html ng-app="photoApp">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Album fotografico</title>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/photoApp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You include the module 'ngResource' but have no reference to angular-resource.js

Edit: ow yeah, same goes ui.bootstrap btw.